# jackson-dataformat-csv - are custom column names possible?

Tags: csv, jackson, export-to-csv

Is it possible to define custom header names when serializing a POJO into CSV.

In other words, if I have a field named `someField` in my PoJO, I would like the header column in output CSV file to be named `Some custom field name` for example.

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sadly no, I tried in several different ways with jackson with no success. I fell back to apache commons csv. I can dig out an example for that if it's of any help to you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's possible with a use of mixins, since you want to use those name only for csv export:

Let assume you have `id` field in your Pojo class with a getter. Then you Create PojoFormat abstract class:

```
public abstract class PojoFormat {
    @JsonProperty("Report Id")
    abstract Integer getId();
}
```

And in your code use it like that:

```
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();

    mapper.addMixIn(Pojo.class, PojoFormat.class);
    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Pojo.class).withHeader();
    mapper.writer(schema).writeValueAsString(objects);
```

Comment: @Piotr I apologize for not noticing your reply all this time. I marked your answer as accepted based on the votes and comments on your post.

Comment: What about csv import?